# llamadas repetidas a formulario

Tags: php, formularios

Una pregunta que supongo que será sencilla pero me tiene atascada.
Estoy intentando hacer un formulario para guardar, por ejemplo, nombres de personas, pero al que se le pueda llamar de forma repetida si el usuario lo desea.
Tengo el formulario, que funciona, y dos botones para poder seguir introduciendo datos o para terminar el proceso.
El problema es que no guarda mas que el primer nombre, no almacena los datos de forma correcta. Yo he pensado en ir acumulando esos datos en un array pero guarda el primero y luego ya no los pasa al hacer click en el botón "siguiente".
Supongo que habrá alguna otra forma de hacer este tipo de cosas pero no doy con ella.
Les dejo el código de lo que tengo pero tal vez sea más fácil que todo esto.

PRUEBA.PHP

```html
<?php

 $nombres = formulario();
  
 //echo "estoy en la principal: ";
 //var_dump($_POST['nombre']);
 //echo "</br>";
 //var_dump($nombres);
  
 botones($_POST['nombre']);



 function botones($nom){
  echo'
   <form action="seguir.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="boton" value="';
      $nom;
    echo' " />
    <input type="submit" value="seguir" />
   </form>
   <a href="acabar.php"><input type="button" value="acabar" /></a>
  ';
 }


 function formulario(){
  
  echo '
   <form action="" method="post">
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre[]" />
    <input type="submit" />
   </form>
  ';
  $nombres=$_POST['nombre'];
    
  return $nombres;
 }

?>
```

SEGUIR.PHP

```html
<?php

//AQUI YA NO LLEGAN LOS VALORES ALAMCENADOS EN PRUEBA.PHP
//ESTAS VARIABLES MUESTRAN NULL
 echo "post: ";
 var_dump($_POST['nombre']);
 echo "</br>nombres";
 var_dump($nom);
 echo "</br>";
 
  $nombres = array_push($nombres, formulario());

 

 function formulario(){
  
  echo '
   <form action="" method="post">
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre[]" />
    <input type="submit"  />
   </form>
  ';
   return $_POST['nombre'];
  
 }

?>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que intentas es algo así:

```
<?php

echo formulario();
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}


function formulario(){
    $txt=null;
    $nombres=null;
    if(isset($_POST['nombre']))
        foreach($_POST['nombre'] as $nombre)
            $nombres.='
                <input type="hidden" name="nombre[]" value="'.$nombre.'">
            ';
    $txt.='
        <form method="post">
            '.$nombres.'
            <input name="nombre[]" autofocus/>
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
    ';  
    return $txt;    
}

?>
```

Más o menos se ve que sabes cómo hacer lo que buscas. Pero te animaría a organizar un poco el código, eso te ayudará a verlo todo más claro. Y, sobre todo, intentar un ejemplo más sencillo. Simplifícalo todo lo que puedas para que podamos ayudarte justo con lo nuevo que resuelve tu duda.

Quedo a tu disposición para ampliar la respuesta con todo lo que necesites saber. Ánimo con ello, se nota que estás poniendo de tu parte para aprender.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tienes razón , me queda mucho por aprender. Me he liado demasiado. Yo creo que partiendo de esto sabré ir ampliándolo, pero si tengo duda, consulataré. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: No, por favor, no te quedes con esa impresión. En este sector todos estamos aprendiendo de forma permanente, porque siempre están saliendo cosas nuevas... Pretendía elogiar tu actitud. El piensa que ya lo sabe todo es el que deja de preguntar, de aprender y se queda estancado.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al final avancé y tengo lo que tenía. Ahora a seguir aprendiendo